# Make HTTP request using Java HTTP client instead of RestTemplate in a Ribbon Eureka application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ribbon, netflix-eureka

Scenario: I have a ribbon eureka service application developed using Java 11. As the RestTemplate does not support InputStream as a response body we need to switch from RestTemplate to another HTTP client, for example, Java 11 HTTP client.

Is there any possibility to configure the Java 11 HTTP client to support ribbon eureka? (or another HTTP client that supports inputStream and can be configured with ribbon eureka)

Comment: You can add a converter to support an `InputStream` why change everything. Also why do you actually need the inputstream. Feels like you are using the resttemplate but are parsing the result yourself instead of using the proper tools.

Comment: Or use a `Resource` instead of `InputStream` to get the content. Instead of switching out the client and have to implement all sorts of things to make it work properly. Or instead of trying to switch out, please describe what you are trying to achieve that you think currently isn't possible with the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I have a huge Json from a third-party service that needs to be parsed as input stream - that's the reason why I need inputStream as a response body.

Comment: As far as I know, the rest template does not support input stream as a response body.

Comment: Use the `execute` method that takes a `ResponseExtractor`, handle the `InputStream` inside that method.

Comment: Do you have an example? I think the inputStream is closed before access it

Comment: I doubt it is closed as that is also the internal mechanism the `RestTemplate` itself uses to convert messages. It is the most low level API.

Answer (score 0):

Don't switch the stack because you think you cannot achieve something. The `postFor` etc. methods on the `RestTemplate` indeed don't allow you to return an `InputStream`. Although you could use a `Resource` but that still will read the whole stream in memory. You probably want to handle the response streaming.

For this low-level access use the [`ResponseExctractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseExtractor.html) with one of the [`execute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#execute-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor-) methods to use it.

```java
restTemplate.execute(url, POST, httpEntityCallback(entity), (res) -> this::handleResponse);
```

```java
private Object handleResponse(ClientHttpResponse res) {
  InputStream in = res.getBody();
  // Do stuff with the input stream
  return null;
}
```

Something along those lines should do the trick.